# Way to create tkinter tabs using OOP

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am using a template to use OOP when creating a GUI and it looks like attached below code (main.py and app.py). How can I modify this to have two tabs? I know it can be done as follow, but I don't know how to apply it in OOP:

```
from tkinter import ttk
  

root = tk.Tk()
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
  
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2')
tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")
```

My file main.py:

```
import app
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x500")
    root.title("title")
    app.App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

And file app.py:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
```